# button that calc prime number in .net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to write program that calculate prime numbers. I searched online and found a code that do that but i am new at .net and having truble to know what to write in the  Button1_Click function.
This is the code i took: **http://www.dotnetperls.com/prime**

This is the code i try to write to preform:

```
  namespace Test
  {
public partial class TestWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsPrime prime = new IsPrime();

    }
}
```

}

i know this is not good question but i really need help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1) In the link you provided  ,they already have a class which is static class which has the method IsPrime.
2) you didn't include that class in your code. I did.
3) In the button click event - I test to see if 7 is a prime number
4) the result will be displayed in a blank page. ( true or false).

```
  namespace Test
  {
      public static class PrimeTool
      {
          public static bool IsPrime(int candidate)
          {
              // Test whether the parameter is a prime number.
              if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
              {
                  if (candidate == 2)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      return false;
                  }
              }

              for (int i = 3;
                  (i * i) <= candidate; i += 2)
              {
                  if ((candidate % i) == 0)
                  {
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              return candidate != 1;
          }
      }



      public partial class TestWebForm: System.Web.UI.Page
      {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
          }

          protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              bool prime = PrimeTool.IsPrime(7); //when a class is static  , you don't `new()` it.
              Response.Write("7 is prime=" + prime);

          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of handing the code on a plate, can you explain to OP what you have done?

Comment: @CodeCaster He has all the code. he just didnt use it in his question. that's all. if you look at the link , they explain pretty well http://i.imgur.com/R539dnC.png

Comment: Probably he don't understand what exactly the code is doing. If you just showing the code from the link add it as an edit of the question, not as an answer ...

Comment: @mybirthname the code in the link is console application. he wanted to use it in asp.net .and this is where he got to trouble. read the question ! Also , he used `IsPrime prime = new IsPrime();` where it doesnt appear _anywhere_ in the link . ( he tries to new() a static class)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Simply do it like this.


namespace Test
      {
    public partial class TestWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = int.Parse(txtNumber.Text);
            Response.Write(IsPrime(number));

        }

        private bool IsPrime(int number){
            int boundary = Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

            if (number == 1) return false;
            if (number == 2) return true;

            for (int i = 2; i <= boundary; ++i)  {
               if (number % i == 0)  return false;
            }

            return true;  
        }
    }

    }
```